# insert values from one sheet into anther

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in one sheet called "Data Storage".  I want to display parts of the data in another sheet.  The first part of the code finds the data based on input from the user i.e. `RPName = Range ("Role Play")`  The next part identifies a range based on "Role Play" that are a series of numbers that will be averaged.

I get an error on this line:

```
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 5), Cells(RPName_tot, 5)).Name = "Com1avg"
```

I can't figure out why that is causing an error.

```
' average Macro
Dim RPName As String, RPName_rng1 As Integer, RPName_rng2 As Integer, RPName_tot As Integer
'get value from Role_Play cell
RPName = Range("Role_Play")
'    MsgBox ("Variable RPNam is selected in Macro average" & RPName)

' Find first instance of RPName
RPName_rng1 = Sheets("Data Storage").Cells.Find(What:=RPName, After:=Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
'    MsgBox RPName_rng1

'Count number of RPname
RPName_rng2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Data Storage").Range("A:A"), RPName)
'    MsgBox RPName_rng2
RPName_tot = RPName_rng1 + RPName_rng2 - 1
'    MsgBox RPName_tot

'Name range here
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 5), Cells(RPName_tot, 5)).Name = "Com1avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 7), Cells(RPName_tot, 7)).Name = "Com2avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 9), Cells(RPName_tot, 9)).Name = "Com3avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 11), Cells(RPName_tot, 11)).Name = "Com4avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 13), Cells(RPName_tot, 13)).Name = "Com5avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 15), Cells(RPName_tot, 15)).Name = "Com6avg"
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Cells(RPName_rng1, 17), Cells(RPName_tot, 17)).Name = "Com7avg"


'    Range("RPData").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("CA_Com1").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com1avg)"
    Range("CA_Com2").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com2avg)"
    Range("CA_Com3").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com3avg)"
    Range("CA_Com4").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com4avg)"
    Range("CA_Com5").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com5avg)"
    Range("CA_Com6").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com6avg)"
    Range("CA_Com7").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Com7avg)"
'    Sheets("Data View").Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the location of your `Cells`, otherwise it will default to the `ActiveSheet`. This becomes much easier (and more readable) using a `With` block.

```
With Sheets("Data Storage")
    .Range(.Cells(RPName_rng1, 5), .Cells(RPName_tot, 5)).Name = "Com1avg"
    ...
End With
```

Note how `.Cells` is used in the `With` block. When this is done, the `Cells` range will be with respect to the sheet defined in the `With` statement.

If you want to do the same without a `With` block, your call would look like this:

```
Sheets("Data Storage").Range(Sheets("Data Storage").Cells(RPName_rng1, 5), Sheets("Data Storage").Cells(RPName_tot, 5)).Name = "Com1avg"
```

Comment: thanks Jason but te With Sheets("Data Storage") gives me a "subscript out of range" error.

Comment: @aoswald - What are the values of `RPName_rng1` and `RPName_tot` when you get the error?

Comment: RPName_rng1 is 6 and RPName_tot is 9

Comment: @aoswald - I updated the answer to show what the call would be without the `With` block. This is the fully qualified statement. Try this and see if you get the same error.