# How to assign values from one sheet into hidden sheet using Excel VBA? (and skip a column within the range?)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Instead of copy-select-pasting cells (lower code), I wish to assign ranges directly and hide the sheet to which values are being filled.

I think the sheet can simply be hidden from view and the macro to fill values based on another sheet's ranges will still work, right?

Trying to assign values on another sheet, I intend to build on this working code (with [thanks to Jason Faulkner and aoswald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726226/insert-values-from-one-sheet-into-anther)). (I must place the cells after one blank column from the last set of values. Ideally, the code will assign values from A13:C## (til the last filled row) and likewise E13:E## immediately after it (i.e. removing column D when assigning values onto the hidden sheet.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim DataRange As Variant, Constraint_sheet As Worksheet, Private_sheet As Worksheet
 Set Constraint_sheet = Sheets("Constraint Sheet")
 Set Private_sheet = Sheets("Private")
 DataRange = Constraint_sheet.Range("A13:C300").Value
 With Private_sheet
   .Range(.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3), .Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(287, 2)) = DataRange
 End With
End Sub
```

Here is working code that I am trying to replace and simplify as indicated above. Are there additional simplifications that can be made?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim MyPassword As String, Private_sheet As Worksheet
  Set Private_sheet = Sheets("Private")
  MyPassword = "string"
  If InputBox("Please enter the password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> MyPassword Then
     Exit Sub
  End If

  Private_sheet.Unprotect MyPassword ' apparently causes clipboard to be erased so do before copying cells

  Columns("B:E").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.Copy

    Private_sheet.Select
Private_sheet.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.Locked = True
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Locked = True
Private_sheet.Protect MyPassword

  ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Edit: Here is the working code I've developed to replace the above code. What further improvements and simplifications can be made?

```
Private Sub AddTemplate_Click()
 Dim Exposed_sheet As Worksheet, Hidden_sheet As Worksheet, MyPassword As String

 Set Exposed_sheet = Sheets("Exposed Sheet")
 Set Hidden_sheet = Sheets("Hidden")

  MyPassword = "string"
  'Reference: carriage return in msgbox http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41581
  If InputBox("Please enter the password to continue." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
   & "Note: The string you type will be exposed, i.e. not '***'." & vbNewLine _
   & "Note: This will save the Excel file!", "Enter Password: Enter the correct string.") <> MyPassword Then
     Exit Sub
  End If

 ' Reference: .Protect -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746478/excel-macro-run-time-error-1004
  Hidden_sheet.Unprotect MyPassword

 'References:
 ' dynamic referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889866/how-to-assign-values-from-one-sheet-into-hidden-sheet-using-excel-vba-and-skip/45889960#45889960
 ' adding text:         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612415/adding-text-to-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba
 ' Union to exclude column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376995/exclude-some-columns-while-copying-one-row-to-other
 With Hidden_sheet
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 3).Resize(UBound(Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value, 1), UBound(Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value, 2)).Value = Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 6).Value = "Volume/Protocol"
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(6, 3).Resize(UBound(Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value, 1), UBound(Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value, 2)).Value = Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value
    ' If you change the order putting this prior, you must change the offsets or the cell they count from. -- DB, Aug 28 2017
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 3).Merge
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Value = Exposed_sheet.Range("A1").Value
 End With

 Hidden_sheet.Protect MyPassword

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that (in a regular code module) `Range()`, `Cells()` will always reference the `ActiveSheet` unless you include a worksheet qualifier

```
Private_sheet.Range(Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3), _
                    Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(287, 2)) = DataRange
```

So even though the outer `Range()` is scoped to `Private_sheet`, that does not "carry through" to the inner `Range` calls.

Should be something like:

```
With Private_sheet
    .Range(.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3), _
           .Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(287, 2)) = DataRange
End With
```

Bit simpler/more flexible:

```
'EDITED
Private_sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3) _
  .Resize(UBound(DataRange, 1), UBound(DataRange, 2)).Value = DataRange
```

In a sheet code module, range references will default to that sheet, but it's still good practise to qualify with a sheet object (eg) `Me.Range()`

Comment: What an active community and prompt response! You posted this answer before I could edit my OP to implement this same solution, which I found in related questions. I am still hopeful for additional improvements to this code. (I will the OP once I have a fuller implementation simplifying the latter code.)

Comment: When I try that 'simpler/more flexible' code, I get the error, 'Run-time error 424: Object required'. I'm wondering if it's because DataRange was defined for a different worksheet using 'with' and somehow this connection was lost when it's used within a different 'with' (i.e. 'with' specifying a different sheet). But when I specify the sheet, sheetname.DataRange, it says 'method or data member not found'.

Comment: Yes I messed that up, forgetting `DataRange` was an array and not a range.  See edit above.